# Magento 2.2.6 installation error

Tags: magento2, error, installation

I tried to install **Magento 2.2.6** in my local server everything is fine actually i reach last stage(**Step 6: Install**) of installation but there i am facing issue like **failed to open stream: Permission denied**.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give the permission to all root folder.

Comment: But how can i changes permission in local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete generated folder content.

use below commands --

> rm -rf var/cache/* generated/*
>
> chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/

Comment: This commands are run in root ?

Comment: yes, in root folder

Comment: Ohk ! Let me try

Comment: getting this error **'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external comman** after first command run.

Comment: which OS you are using ?

Comment: I am using Windows...

Comment: @PratikPatel Local server installed in C:/ drive?

Comment: Yuppppppp......

Comment: then you can try deleting `generated` folder manually and set read-write permission to `var` and `generated` folder

Comment: Where i can found **generated** folder ?

Comment: its in root folder

Comment: let me know your output please

Comment: Yippii ! I have removed generated folder and after that Successfully installed magento...Thanks for your quick help @Shashank :)

Comment: @PratikPatel, sounds good. please mark it as answer